# Different behavior can see in the Windows PerfMon for the java process

Tags: java, windows, memory, memory-management, jvm

We are monitoring(Using Windows Perfmon) our system in the windows environment(We are monitoring the Working Set).

We can see that memory consumption for the java process is very much tally with the committed heap pattern as follows in the production environment.

OS:- Windows Server 2008 R2 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1
JVM :- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE   (1.7.0_79-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 12:36:16 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600
 -Xms7000M 
 -Xmx7000M

[image]

but when we check the same setup in the local machine(Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23569)) I can see the different pattern. This pattern is more tally with the used heap size not to the committed heap size as follows.

[image]

I can see so many memory drops in the Perfmon which is running on the production setup but not in the local setup.

Any idea on this difference ?

Comment: seems almost impossible to say why this is without seeing the code... though I understand posting the whole code may also make the question too large

Comment: perhaps you can use other profiling tools to see which parts of your program are using the memory?